# How to get url in getstaticpath nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have face trubble to get url in getStaticPath

```
export const getStaticPaths = async (props) => {
  if (url === 'blah') {
    return {
      paths: [
        { params: { pid: "create" } },
      ],
      fallback: true,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by URL here? Is it the full URL of the page you're rendering, is it just the path? Either way, that's not something you'd get from inside `getStaticPaths`, that function is used to generate the paths that will be built for a given dynamic route.

Comment: I need page url inside getStaticpath

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use getStaticProps() if you just to get a params

```
// pages/posts/[id].js

function Post({ post }) {
  // Render post...
}

// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }))

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}

// This also gets called at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // params contains the post `id`.
  // If the route is like /posts/1, then params.id is 1
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.id}`)
  const post = await res.json()

  // Pass post data to the page via props
  return { props: { post } }
}

export default Post
```

but if you want to get path as well you can use:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

//inside of your component
const { asPath } = useRouter()
```

Comment: Where are you retrieving the URL in `getStaticProps`?

Comment: whenever you call this function it gets the "context" as a parameter in which you have params

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't contain the URL. Only the params passed from `getStaticPaths`.

Comment: useRouter() hook returns a route object, which has two properties to get the pathname.

`One is asPath property, and

Another one is pathname property.`

Comment: `useRouter` can't be used from inside `getStaticProps`, you can only use it on the client-side.